# Facebook graph api. App notifications: A client gets notification, but server gets error in the response: Unsupported post request

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, web, notifications

I'm developing backend by Java of an online game for facebook. I need to send app notifications using "facebook graph api". When I try to send a notification, facebook returns the next response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

My request looks like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/0123456789/notifications?access_token=9876543210|DJaspodJDduSkskaurrbqdd&template=Test+message`

Most strange thing is I get notifications in my facebook account but my server side gets error after sending one and I can't understand if a user has gotten a notification. I wander if someone had problem like this. I will appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem! I just added parameter "href" to the request. Tell the truth I don't need that parameter but facebook wants it so that I added to it value similar to a link.

Now it looks like this: https://graph.facebook.com/0123456789/notifications?access_token=9876543210|DJaspodJDduSkskaurrbqdd&template=Test+message&href=fbWantsThisLink.html?butIDontNeedIt=123

Maybe this solution will be helpfull to someone!